# Protractor Jasmine Reporter + BDD + Azure DevOps

Tags: jasmine, protractor, azure-devops, bdd

I would like to write Jasmine End 2 End Tests in a BDD style. From what I've learned, this means, I have pretty much 4 areas:

- Feature
- Scenario
- stimulus or event
- Outcomes to ensure

From my naive view, I would create a test for the "Individual Details" feature like this:

```
// Feature
describe('Showing Individual Details', () => {
  let individualDetailsPage: IndividualDetailsPage;

  beforeEach(() => {
    individualDetailsPage = new IndividualDetailsPage();
  });

  // Scenario - New Individual
  describe('Given a new Individual', () => {
    beforeEach(async () => {
      await individualDetailsPage.navigateToDetails('-1');
    });

    // Incoming Event
    describe('When the Details are loaded', () => {
      // Ensure outcome
      it('Then all Controls are empty', async () => {
        expect(individualDetailsPage.firstNameInput.text).toBe('');
        expect(individualDetailsPage.lastNameInput.text).toBe('');
        expect(individualDetailsPage.birthdateInput.text).toBe('');
      });

      // Ensure outcome
      it('Then the save button is disabled', () => {
        expect(individualDetailsPage.saveButton.isEnabled).toBe(false);
      });
    });
  });
});
```

Therefore, for the Individual Details feature, if a new Individual is set, then the Controls should be empty and the save button disabled.
Still from a naive view, this seems alright. Also running the tests, I see:

[image]

Which seems alright. Now the interesting part: I would like to publish this changes to Azure DevOps, therefore I'm using the following code in the protractor config:

```
  onPrepare() {
    require('ts-node').register({
      project: require('path').join(__dirname, './tsconfig.e2e.json')
    });
    var jasmineReporters = require('jasmine-reporters');
    var junitReporter = new jasmineReporters.JUnitXmlReporter({
      savePath: 'testresults',
      filePrefix: 'e2e-tests',
      consolidateAll: true
    });

    jasmine.getEnv().addReporter(junitReporter);
  }
```

Unfortunately, the XML is looking like this:

```
 <testsuite name="Showing Individual Details" timestamp="2019-02-04T18:23:33" hostname="localhost" time="2.035" errors="0" tests="0" skipped="0" disabled="0" failures="0">
 </testsuite>
 <testsuite name="Showing Individual Details.Given a new Individual" timestamp="2019-02-04T18:23:33" hostname="localhost" time="2.033" errors="0" tests="0" skipped="0" disabled="0" failures="0">
 </testsuite>
 <testsuite name="Showing Individual Details.Given a new Individual.When the Details are loaded" timestamp="2019-02-04T18:23:33" hostname="localhost" time="2.033" errors="0" tests="2" skipped="0" disabled="0" failures="0">
  <testcase classname="Showing Individual Details.Given a new Individual.When the Details are loaded" name="Then all Controls are empty" time="1.106" />
  <testcase classname="Showing Individual Details.Given a new Individual.When the Details are loaded" name="Then the save button is disabled" time="0.927" />
 </testsuite>
```

Since Azure DevOps only seems to check for the name, I then see:

[image]

My problem: I don't know exactly, where my problem lies. I didn't find any good resources regarding "real" BDD with Jasmine, also it seems like the Jasmine Reporter can't be configured that much: https://github.com/larrymyers/jasmine-reporters

Is therefore my code totally wrong, or is it in fact the reporter? And if this is the case, are there alternatives or would I need to "flatten" the XML somehow?

Comment: You could write a custom reporter to format the xml file the way you want it. It's actually easier than you think it would be. Check here for an idea of how to get started https://jasmine.github.io/2.1/custom_reporter.html

Answer (score 1):

I agree with the comment above, creating your own reporter sound like the way to go. You can format the contents however you like.

I recently responded to another question regarding Jasmine reporter [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54590433/10836734). I was reformatting my test results into a JSON object and storing them in amazons dynamoDB after each test completed.

Any more questions let me know.

Comment: Thank you very much. What I find strange: Azure DevOps is quite popular and so is Protractor. I can't be the first person having the problem, since the test result is pretty much useless.

Comment: Unfortunately I'm not too familiar with Azure but have a bit of experience with AWS pipelines. Is your project in a automated pipeline also or are you manually uploading the results for Azure to interpret itself? If it is the latter there is another format of report protractor can automatically generate by setting `resultJsonOutputFile:true` in the conf file.

Answer (score 0):

you can use the useFullTestName property:

```
jasmine.getEnv().addReporter(new jasmineReporters.JUnitXmlReporter({
      consolidateAll: true,
      useFullTestName:true,
      savePath: 'e2e/output',
      filePrefix: 'xmlresults'
    }));
```

Answer (score 0):

I would like to recommend using the Jasmine TRX Reporter instead of the JUnit XML Reporter.
The TRX Reporter also supports adding **screenshots** to the published test results, which is a big plus in a CI/CD environment.
The screenshot will be available in Azure Devops under the attachments tab of the test case result:
[image: Attachment tab in Azure Devops]

You can add it to your project with:

```
npm install jasmine-trx-reporter --save-dev
```

And add it to you protractor config like so:

```
const TrxReporter = require('jasmine-trx-reporter');

...

    onPrepare() {

...

        jasmine.getEnv().addReporter(new TrxReporter({
            folder: require('path').join(__dirname, './testresults/'),
            takeScreenshotsOnlyOnFailures: true
        }));

...
```

And last but not least, change the Publish Test Result step in your Release to use VSTest  instead of JUnit and the exported .trx file instead of the .xml file.

Comment: below is the task I have used but it throws warning message ##[warning]No test result files matching **/*.trx were found.and not showing results - task: PublishTestResults@2
  inputs:
    testResultsFormat: 'VSTest'
    testResultsFiles: '**/*.trx'
    searchFolder: '$(Build.SourcesDirectory)'
    publishRunAttachments: true
    mergeTestResults: false
    failTaskOnFailedTests: true

Comment: @PDTech take a look at your PublishTestResults task, you might need to finetune the glob for "Test results files". I've just used **.trx