# Capture Total Time or duration of a Test Suite using Jasmine Hook

Tags: node.js, jasmine, protractor

I have been trying to retrieve 'totalTime' from the jasmineDone hook or 'duration' from SuiteResult as documented at [https://jasmine.github.io/api/edge/global.html#] but they don't seem to be available. Would be grateful for any pointers?

I found @DublinDev answer to this [Jasmine get current test result](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54589571/jasmine-get-current-test-result]) which was so helpful. This allows me to get the duration per test using the specDone hook which I could potentially use and add each result, but I am curious to know if I am doing something wrong.

I am using the following code from the link above( 2nd link) and would expect either of the console.logs to output a time but neither are outputting anything

```
function dbReporter() {

  this.jasmineStarted = function (options) { };

  this.specStarted = function (result) { };

  this.specDone = async function (result) { };

  this.suiteStarted = function (result) { };

  this.suiteDone = function (result) {
    console.log('duration=', result.duration)
  }
  this.jasmineDone = async function (result) {
    console.log('totalTime=', result.totalTime)
  }
}

module.exports = dbReporter;
```

Comment: Hey, glad you found my previous answer helpful! I would also expect this to work. Can you confirm the version of Jasmine you are using? It appears the `totalTime` property was only added to the result object for `jasmineDone` in the [latest (3.5) release](https://jasmine.github.io/api/3.5/global.html#JasmineDoneInfo). Here is [3.4 release to compare](https://jasmine.github.io/api/3.4/global.html#JasmineDoneInfo)

Comment: Hi DublinDev, I was hoping you were out there somewhere:-) I am using latest version 3.5 which makes it all the more confusing. However just had a thought that perhaps my local version is not correct. will just have a look

Comment: Do those console logs not get activated at all or do they print `totalTime= undefined`?

Comment: I have checked and versions seem ok and up to date

Comment: yes they both print as undefined

Comment: Do you have protractor installed locally in project or globally? If you run `node_modules\.bin\jasmine -v` from your node project is it the same version?

Comment: Can you also try print `console.log('res obj=', result)`. This should show you what properties and methods are available to the results object

Comment: hi there, I have run the code you provided locally in my project and it is showing as jasmine v3.5.0. if I output just the result object, duration or totalTime are not shown for either hooks. If you output the object are  you seeing duration or totalTime?

Comment: I actually am using an older version of jasmine and likely protractor. Is there any chance you have protractor installed globally also? Check by running `jasmine -v` without the node prefix. The command used to launch protractor will determine if it uses a local or global installation. If you are using `protractor` it is likely global, if you are using `node_modules\.bin\protractor`,`node_modules\protractor\node_modules\bin\protractor` or have a script setup in your package.json it is likely local

Comment: Sorry I missed your previous question, yes I run protractor locally within project  and when i run 'node_modules\.bin\jasmine -v' I get jasmine v3.5.0. Maybe the best option is to just add the separate values I get from specDone for now, as i think that's how the derive the duration value anyway. I really appreciate all your input as you have confirmed what I am trying should work so thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Given that you have the latest version of Jasmine already I would recommend just making your own timer which starts in jasmineStarted hook and ends in JasmineDone hook.

```
onPrepare: () => {

    //Create a global variable to be used for the timer
    global.jasmineTimer = 0;

    jasmine.getEnv().addReporter({
        jasmineStarted: function (options) {
            jasmineTimer = Date.now();
            console.log(`Starting execution ${jasmineTimer}`)
        },
        jasmineDone: async function (result) {

            console.log(`Finished execution in ${(Date.now() - jasmineTimer) / 1000}s`)
        }
    })
}
```

[image: Screenshot of output]